# How we can get animation complete listner for motion layout in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, declarative-programming

Here is my question how do I get a complete animation listener for motion layout in jetpack compose?

My purpose is to do that I want to trigger another animation after completing the motion layout animation.

And another question is how to do sequence animation in jetpack compose.

Comment: Clarify your answer with code. Difficult to give a solution without context